# So specific, adding a image of the artist to the table view of recent songs in a joomla component

Tags: php, mysql, sql, joomla

I want to have the image of the artist (song artist) available in the viewing of the recent songs. 
here are the php files and the tables of the database i guess you might need when answering:
(I'd be happy if someone would teach me so fast how to use query commands for selecting a data like this in a crossed usage of tables not just one row of the tables. if no plz change the code so it views artist picture)

**Here is the helper php code**

```
<?php

// no direct access
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');

class modMusColRecentlyAddedSongsHelper
{


function getSongs(&$params)
{
    global $mainframe;
    $_db    = & JFactory::getDBO();
    $model      = modMusColRecentlyAddedSongsHelper::getModel();

        $limit = $params->get( 'n_songs', 5 );

        if($params->get( 'artist_id' )) $where_clause[] = " s.artist_id = " . $params->get( 'artist_id' ) . " " ;

        if ($params->get( 'genre_id' )) {
            $genre_id = $params->get( 'genre_id' );
            $model->getDescendantsId($genre_id); 
            $descendants = $model->descendantsId;
            $descendants[] = $genre_id ;
            $genre_clause = ' ( s.genre_id = ' . implode(' OR s.genre_id = ',$descendants) . ' ) ';
            $where_clause[] = $genre_clause;
        }


            //$where_clause[] = ' ra.type = "song" ';
            $where_clause = (count($where_clause) ? ' WHERE '.implode(' AND ', $where_clause) : '');

            $query =    ' SELECT s.*, ar.artist_name,al.name as album_name, AVG(ra.points) as points FROM #__muscol_songs as s '.
                        ' LEFT JOIN #__muscol_albums as al ON al.id = s.album_id '.
                        ' LEFT JOIN #__muscol_artists as ar ON ar.id = s.artist_id '.
                        ' LEFT JOIN #__muscol_ratings as ra ON ra.album_id = s.id AND ra.type = "song" '.
                        $where_clause .
                        ' GROUP BY s.id ' .
                        ' ORDER BY s.added DESC '.
                        ' LIMIT '. $limit;

                        //echo $query;die;


        $_db->setQuery( $query );
        $recent_songs = $_db->loadObjectList();

        //print_r($query);die;

        return $recent_songs;

}

function getModel()
{
    if (!class_exists( 'ArtistsModelSearch' ))
    {
        // Build the path to the model based upon a supplied base path
        $path = JPATH_SITE.DS.'components'.DS.'com_muscol'.DS.'models'.DS.'search.php';
        $false = false;

        // If the model file exists include it and try to instantiate the object
        if (file_exists( $path )) {
            require_once( $path );
            if (!class_exists( 'ArtistsModelSearch' )) {
                JError::raiseWarning( 0, 'Model class ArtistsModelSearch not found in file.' );
                return $false;
            }
        } else {
            JError::raiseWarning( 0, 'Model ArtistsModelSearch not supported. File not found.' );
            return $false;
        }
    }

    $model = new ArtistsModelSearch();

    return $model;
}

}
```

**Here is the default.php code**

```
<?php // no direct access
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access'); ?>
<?php
if($params->get( 'Itemid' )) $itemid = "&Itemid=".$params->get( 'Itemid' );
   else $itemid = "";
   $document =& JFactory::getDocument();
   $document->addStyleSheet(JURI::base(true).'/modules/mod_muscol_recently_added_songs/tmpl/recently_added_songs.css');
?>

 <div class='recently_added_songs'>
 <table border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' width="100%">
 <thead>
 <tr>
  <th> <?php echo JText::_( 'آهنگ' ); ?> </th>
   <? if($params->get('show_album')){ ?><th> <?php echo JText::_( 'آلبوم' ); ?> </th><? } ?>
  <? if($params->get('show_artist')){ ?><th> <?php echo JText::_( 'خواننده' ); ?> </th><? } ?>
  <? if($params->get('show_rating')){ ?><th> <?php echo JText::_( 'امتياز' ); ?> </th><? } ?>
</tr>
</thead>
<?php
 $n = 0;
  for ($j=0, $m=count( $songs ); $j < $m; $j++) {
 $song = $songs[$j];
$link= JRoute::_( 'index.php?option=com_muscol&view=song&id='. $song->id . $itemid);
$link_album= JRoute::_( 'index.php?option=com_muscol&view=album&id='. $song->album_id . $itemid);
$link_artist= JRoute::_( 'index.php?option=com_muscol&view=artist&id='. $song->artist_id . $itemid);

//$image = MusColHelper::createThumbnail($album->image, $album->name, $params->get('default_width'), $image_attr);
?>
 <tr class="tr_recent_songs <?php echo "row$n"; ?>">
  <td><a href="<?php echo $link; ?>"><?php echo $song->name; ?></a></td>
  <? if($params->get('show_album')){ ?><td><a href="<?php echo $link_album; ?>"><?php echo $song->album_name; ?></a></td><? } ?>
  <? if($params->get('show_artist')){ ?><td><a href="<?php echo $link_artist; ?>"><?php echo $song->artist_name; ?></a></td><? } ?>
  <? if($params->get('show_rating')){ ?><td><?php echo MusColHelper::show_stars($song->points,false,false,false,true);?></td><? } ?>
</tr>
<?php
$n = 1 - $n ;
}
?>
 </table>
</div>
```

**songs** table in the database (name of the table is songs)

```
id  album_id  num  disc_num  length  name  lyrics  artist_id  composer_id  filename  extension  review  songwriters  chords  genre_id  hits  buy_link  video  position  downloaded  user_id
```

**artists** table in the database  (the artist picture should be read from picture column)

```
id artist_name  image  review  letter  class_name  related  keywords  added  hits  country  picture  user_id  metakeywords  metadescription  city  years_active  url  genre_id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already query the right tables in the helper, so -provided the code you show already works - all you need is to return the extra field:

```
  $query =    ' SELECT s.*, ar.artist_name,al.name
```

becomes

```
  $query =    ' SELECT s.*, ar.artist_name,ar.image as artistimage, al.name
```

then in the view:

```
<?php echo $song->artist_name; ?>
```

becomes

```
<?php echo  $song->artist_name;
echo sprintf('<img src="%s" class="artistpic" />',$song->artistimage);
 ?>
```

Comment: I've a problem, :-p somethings not working, :) 
no image shown (sorry for delay) I didnt had time to test this earlier.
Any hint to check out what's wrong?

Comment: sure, look at the markup in the browser (using firebug or the like) and see what you wrote as a src attribute, you might have a wrong path.  If there is no src then try to JError::raiseNotice(100,var_export($song,true)) or var_dump($song) to see what's missing.

Comment: also why do you have arabic keys as language constants  JText::_( 'آلبوم' )? It really makes no sense, the arabic should be in your language file and you should have english constants, else it would be quite tough to translate your component to other languages.

Comment: hmm about the Arabic constant :D you're right :) I'd been a bit lazy :) 

I'd been working on the language file creation earlier, I'm fixing things like this.:)
and this is not Arabic :) this is Persian :) 
Although there might be an Arabic relevant meaning of this word just the same it is in Persian, since Album is an English word imported to both of the languages. But I'm from Iran :)

I'd fix things like this UTF constant (generally speaking, regardless the language :) ) soon :) be sure :) 
ThanQ , I'll check out these and inform you ;)